# Consistently parsing date from JSON timestamp in Javascript across browsers

Tags: javascript, datetime, cross-browser, timestamp

I have a JSON response from a service where a date field is encoded as timestamp. The value `1251756000000` is supposed to represent September 2009 (I need only month and year).

I have found that the script I'm working on is not consistent across browsers.

On Firefox 22 `new Date(response.responseJSON.startDate).getYear()` returns 109 and must be added to 1900 to get a consistent value.

On IE10 in IE7 compatibility mode the constant `1900` **must not be added**.

The question is: how to consistently parse a timestamp in Javascript in order to get month and year?

PS month is consistent across the two browsers.

Comment: The web appplication **must** be compatible with IE7 other than modern browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing is correct (provided you made sure the timestamp is UTC), the error is in the use you make of the `Date` instance.

Don't use `getYear` but `getFullYear`.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) :

> The value returned by getFullYear is an absolute number. For dates
>   between the years 1000 and 9999, getFullYear returns a four-digit
>   number, for example, 1995. Use this function to make sure a year is
>   compliant with years after 2000.
>
> Use this method instead of the getYear method.

Comment: It's so weird to see that Microsoft adheres to specifications found on Mozilla website instead of a *super-partes* website

Comment: The real specification is ECMAScript, the MDN just happens to be the most readable documentation.